# Как в Windows установить и использовать ПО, рассчитанное только для компьютеров Apple?

Tags: windows, macos, windows-7

Вопрос почти по программированию, но не относится ни к одному из остальных форумов сервиса.
Есть некоторое программное обеспечение для создания приложений под iPhone (в моем случае PhoneGap), которое работает под системой, как написано в документации, "`Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6)`". Но вот проблема, я не могу нигде найти компьютер Apple. Как, имея Windows 7, установить и использовать программное обеспечение, рассчитанное только для компьютеров Apple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Поставить [хакинтош](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86).
2. Поставить OS X на [виртуальную машину](http://appstudio.org/blog/7221).